# I Create A apex Class and trigger for the Account for the relevent contact creation and it is showing Like This

Tags: apex, trigger

//Apex Class

```
public class ContactInsert {
    Public Static Void AutomaticContactCreation(List<Account> newList){
        List<Contact> con =new List<Contact>();
        For(Account acc:newList){
            Contact cc =new Contact();
            cc.AccountId=acc.Id;
            cc.Phone=acc.Phone;
            cc.LastName=acc.Name;
           cc.Fax=acc.Fax;
            cc.MailingState=acc.BillingState;
            cc.MailingCity=acc.BillingCity;
            
        }
    }

}
```

//Trigger

```
trigger ContactCreation on Contact (after insert ) {
    if(Trigger.IsInsert == true ){
    ContactCreation.AutomaticContactCreation(Trigger.new);
    }  
}
```

//Error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> AutomaticContactCreation(List) from the type ContactCreation

Comment: class name is `ContactInsert` but on your trigger you have `ContactCreation`

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is ContactInsert and you are calling the method using ContactCreation. Also, you have written the trigger on Contact and passing Trigger.New which is a list of contacts but the method AutomaticContactCreation is expecting a list of accounts which is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Try this `ContactInsert.AutomaticContactCreation(Trigger.new);`

Comment: Explaining _why_ something should work is as important as the solution itself. Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this should work.